# How to create a quiz score variable in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset in R similar to the following, where each row belongs to a person who has taken a quiz:

```
example <- tibble(ID = c(1,2,3),
                  age = c(12,12,11),
                  Q1 = c(T,T,T),
                  Q2 = c(F,F,T),
                  Q3 = c(F,T,F))
```

| ID | age | Q1 | Q2 | Q3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12 | TRUE | FALSE | FALSE |
| 2 | 12 | TRUE | FALSE | TRUE |
| 3 | 11 | TRUE | TRUE | FALSE |

I want to score each person's quiz in a variable called "score". For example, if I know the correct answers are True for Q1, True for Q2, and and False for Q3, it should look like this:

| ID | age | Q1 | Q2 | Q3 | score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12 | TRUE | FALSE | FALSE | 66.7 |
| 2 | 12 | TRUE | FALSE | TRUE | 33.3 |
| 3 | 11 | TRUE | TRUE | FALSE | 100 |

What's the best way to do this in R over many questions (say 50), and other variables in the data set? I imagine we might want a row of the answer key and create a mean score based on equality of the rows?

Comment: You'll want to use dplyr's mutate function and you'll probably need to create a function.

Answer (score 1):

```
correct <- c(T, T, F)

example %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(score = mean(unlist(c_across(Q1:Q3) == correct))*100)

     ID   age Q1    Q2    Q3    score
  <dbl> <dbl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <dbl>
1     1    12 TRUE  FALSE FALSE  66.7
2     2    12 TRUE  FALSE TRUE   33.3
3     3    11 TRUE  TRUE  FALSE 100  


example %>%
  left_join(pivot_longer(.,-c(ID, age)) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(score = 100 * mean(value == correct)))
     ID   age Q1    Q2    Q3    score
  <dbl> <dbl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <dbl>
1     1    12 TRUE  FALSE FALSE  66.7
2     2    12 TRUE  FALSE TRUE   33.3
3     3    11 TRUE  TRUE  FALSE 100
```

in base R:

```
cbind(example, score = colMeans(t(as.matrix(example[-(1:2)]))==correct) * 100)

  ID age   Q1    Q2    Q3     score
1  1  12 TRUE FALSE FALSE  66.66667
2  2  12 TRUE FALSE  TRUE  33.33333
3  3  11 TRUE  TRUE FALSE 100.00000
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible base R solution:

```
correct <- c(T, T, F)

example$score <-
  rowMeans(t(apply(example[, 3:ncol(example)], 1, function(x)
    x == correct))) * 100
```

**Output**

```
     ID   age Q1    Q2    Q3    score
  <dbl> <dbl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <dbl>
1     1    12 TRUE  FALSE FALSE  66.7
2     2    12 TRUE  FALSE TRUE   33.3
3     3    11 TRUE  TRUE  FALSE 100
```